# Why this 'Perhaps a missing \item' error with the algorithmic package?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying to imitate an example I found in the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) to write my own algorithm using the `algorithmic` package. I can't understand it clearly, though, and I am getting errors all the time.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{alltt}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{parskip}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}
 \caption{Assigning j to a center}
 \begin{algorithmic}  
 INITIALIZE $C = \emptyset$
 \FOR {i=1,...,r}  <------Error
 \IF {$N_i \cap N_{i_0} \neq\emptyset$ for some $i_0 \leq i$
 \STATE assign to $p_{i_0}$ all demand nodes j with $i \in   \widetilde{p_j}$
 \ELSE
 \STATE $C = C \cup \{ i \}$ and assign to $p_i$ all the demand nodes $j$ with  $i \in   \widetilde{p_j}$
 \ENDIF
 \ENDFOR
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

I am getting the error:  `Something is wrong. Perphaps a missing \item` on the line with the `\FOR` command. Can anybody help?

Comment: You haven't closed the group/argument to `\IF`.

Comment: You are right though the error still persists cause it is in the line above I guess. I added the } and I am still getting it

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems: you had a missing closing brace for the `\IF` and you were using `INITIALIZE` in a forbidden place (the beginning of the list internally used). Perhaps you could use

```
\STATE INITIALIZE $C = \emptyset$
```

or any other of the keywords provided by the package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
 \caption{Assigning j to a center}
 \begin{algorithmic}  
 \STATE INITIALIZE $C = \emptyset$
 \FOR {i=1,...,r}
 \IF {$N_i \cap N_{i_0} \neq\emptyset$ for some $i_0 \leq i$}
 \STATE assign to $p_{i_0}$ all demand nodes j with $i \in   \widetilde{p_j}$
 \ELSE
 \STATE $C = C \cup \{ i \}$ and assign to $p_i$ all the demand nodes $j$ with  $i \in   \widetilde{p_j}$
 \ENDIF
 \ENDFOR
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did it, simultaneously with your comments. Thanks again